# Knowing start_time and duration in minute, How to get end_time in js?

Tags: javascript

I need to pass start_time and end_time to the database, for convenience I choose to get input of start time and the duration time.

The start_time is just the 4-digit TIME type (`HH:mm`), and the duration is INT in minutes.

I have the input codes here.

```
<div className="col-5 col-3 col-1">
    <label htmlFor="time">Time: </label>
        <input type="time" list="time" onChange={(event) => {
            setStart_time(event.target.value)
    }} required />
</div>

<div className="col-5 col-3 col-1">
    <label htmlFor="duration">Duration: </label>
        <input type="int" list="duration" placeholder={"Minutes.."} onChange={(event) => {
            setEnd_time(event.target.value)
    }} required />
</div>
```

I'm a beginner, how could I express to make the `setEnd_time` able to get the correct time?

For example, if I input 15:30 in the start_time, and 60 for the duration, the end_time will be 16:30.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: I tried to plus the duration input value and the `setStart_time` value. but it returns a string like 6015:30, I believe it's a js issue that I'm not know how to express the time change.

Comment: Please share more details, and add all clarification to your question by editing it. For example, what does "4-digit TIME type" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the following function to add min duration to `HH:mm` time format.

```
function addMinDurationtoHM(str, durationMin) {
  var p = str.split(':');
  var h = parseInt(p[0]), m = parseInt(p[1]);

  if(h > 23 || m > 59) throw new Error("Invalid time");

  m += durationMin;
  h += parseInt(m/60);
  m %= 60;
  h %= 12;

  return (h<10 ? '0'+h : h)+":"+(m<10 ? '0'+m : m);
}

// Example:
console.log(addMinDurationtoHM("24:28", 32));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. just one thing in my case, I took the duration value from input into this function, the value was regarded as string, even though the input type is int, the `m += duration;` will be some string like `060` or `5030`. I parseInt the duration to int and added to `m`, then all solved.

Comment: @Chenchen no matter the input type the value is always a string

Comment: @ManosKounelakis Why is it always a string? Then, what is the type attribute in the input used for? Is it only used to check user's input?

Comment: At some point you will call .innerText or .innerHTML to get the value (or even .value) All the above return string values. The type attribute is used to let the browser know how to render the input and perform relevant validations